# How can I specify the number of the trees in my xgboost model ,using xgb.train?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, xgboost

If I use xgb.train, how can i specify the number of the trees in my model ?

In xgboost.XGBRegressor(), I know i can use parameter 'n_estimators'， but what should I do in xgb.train()?

I searched Google and didn't find any answer, thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, did you solve your problem?

Comment: @VivekKumar Yes, thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its `num_boost_round`. As stated on the [api documentation](http://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html):

> num_boost_round (int) – Number of boosting iterations.

To exactly match the output of xgb.train and scikit wrapper (XGBRegressor or XGBClassifier) you can look at my other answer here:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/46947191/3374996