# What is the difference between num_boost_round and n_estimators

Tags: python, xgboost

I saw that some `xgboost` methods take a parameter `num_boost_round`, like this:

```
model = xgb.cv(params, dtrain,  num_boost_round=500, early_stopping_rounds=100)
```

Others however take `n_estimators` like this:

```
model_xgb = xgb.XGBRegressor(n_estimators=360, max_depth=2, learning_rate=0.1)
```

As far as I understand, each time boosting is applied a new estimator is created. Is that nor correct?

If that is so, then the numbers `num_boost_round` and  `n_estimators` should be equal, right?

Comment: Yes you are correct. Please look at the following question: [How to get Predictions with XGBoost and XGBoost using Scikit-Learn Wrapper to match?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46943674/how-to-get-predictions-with-xgboost-and-xgboost-using-scikit-learn-wrapper-to-ma)

Answer (score 24):

Yes they are the same, both referring to the same parameter ([see the docs here](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html#module-xgboost.sklearn), or [the github issue](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/2854#issuecomment-341568674)).

The reason of the different name is because `xgb.XGBRegressor` is an implementation of the scikit-learn API; and scikit-learn conventionally uses `n_estimators` to refer to the number of boosting stages (for example the [GradientBoostingClassifier](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.GradientBoostingClassifier.html))

Comment: The author of xgboost also uses `n_estimators` in xgbclassfier and `num_boost_round`, got knows why in the same api he wants to do this. :(

Comment: I accidentally set both of them to a high number during the same optimization and the optimization time seems to have multiplied. I wonder if setting them both to 1000 is equivalent to setting the boosting rounds to a million.

Answer (score 0):

num_parallel_tree in XGBoost native API is equivalent to n_estimators.